# Create specific FILETIME struct in C++

Tags: c++, utc, systemtime, filetime

I've done research on MSDN and this site relating to my question, but have been unsuccessful in finding a specific, non-hacky solution.

I would like to have the ability to create specific UTC FILETIME struct in C++. The user has the ability to specify a date (YYYY/MM/DD) and then I would like to have the time of this date be 00:00. So far, this is what I have:

```
FILETIME ft;
SYSTEMTIME st;

st.wYear = myYear;
st.wMonth = myMonth;
st.wDay = myDay;
st.wHour = 0;
st.wMinute = 0;
st.wSecond = 0;
st.wMilliseconds = 0;

SystemTimeToFileTime(&st, &ft);
```

The issue I run into is that the local time zone information is used on my machine to generate a FILETIME that is different from the specified YYYY/MM/DD 00:00. The goal is to have a FILETIME struct that contains this information so that it is not time zone dependent.

I've considered using GetTimeZoneInformation() to find the UTC offset and perform mathematical calculations to vary st.wHour, st.wMinute, and st.wSecond, but was unsure as to if there was a better solution to simply create a specific FILETIME instance.

EDIT:

The resultant output I seek is  FILETIME structure with the given myYear, myMonth, and myDay, and "hardcoded" time of 00:00 (UTC).

Comment: My apologies, I may have worded the question poorly. That function was able to give me a correct time conversion to UTC, that is - with the appropriate offset, but what I would like to have is a resultant FILETIME instance such that the Year, Month, and Day stay the same, and the UTC time is 00:00, regardless of the timezone attributes present when performing the conversion. Thus, I want the resultant FILETIME structure to always be specified Year, Month, and Day, and "hardcoded" time of 00:00.

Comment: SystemTimeToFileTime() assumes that the given system time is local time.  So you get the UTC offset and the DST adjustment in the FILETIME and it won't be 12:00 midnight anymore.  A simple way to correct is to go back to local time, use FileTimeToLocalFileTime()

Comment: What is the proper series of events? Use SystemTimeToFileTime first and then call FileTimeToLocalFileTime on the FILETIME structure output from the original call to SystemTimeToFileTime? When doing this I get (as an example) June 3, 2015 00:00:00 as my SYSTEMTIME structure with a resultant June 2, 2015 18:00:00 (UTC) as my resultant FILETIME structure, but I would like the FILETIME structure to be June 3, 2015 00:00:00 (UTC).